# Only accept certain characters in the user input

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this code but the application enters a break mode and tells me there is an unhandled exception: Value cannot be null  whenever a user enters anything other than A,B,C,D I have addressed the issue but my code does not seem to work.

```
 private async void Confirm_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUserEntry.Text != null)
        {
            if (txtUserEntry.Text == "A")
            { 
                await DisplayAlert("Wrong answer", "Sorry", "Next question");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Quiz_Page2());
            }
            else if (txtUserEntry.Text == "B")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Wrong answer", "Sorry", "Next question");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Quiz_Page2());
            }
            else if (txtUserEntry.Text == "C")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Wrong answer", "Sorry", "Next question");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Quiz_Page2());
            }
            else if (txtUserEntry.Text == "D")
            {
                scoreSettings.GlobalScore++;
                await DisplayAlert("Correct answer", "Well done", "Next question");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Quiz_Page2());
            }
            else if (txtUserEntry.Text != "A" || txtUserEntry.Text != "B" || txtUserEntry.Text != "C" || txtUserEntry.Text != "D")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Please type either A,B,C,D", "", "");
            }

            else await DisplayAlert("Please type either A,B,C,D", "", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click confirm with invalid input?

Comment: "it errors" - what does this mean?  Do you get an error or exception?  What is the EXACT error/exception?

Comment: The application enters a break mode and tells me there is an unhandled exception: Value cannot be null

Comment: first, the logic in your 5th case will be satisfied by ANY input, including A-E.  You generally want to AND multiple negative statements, not OR them.  Second, examining the stack trace on an unhandled exception should show you what line caused it.  Finally, have you tried passing values (not empty strings) to DisplayAlert?

Comment: [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
04-28 18:58:23.145 E/mono-rt ( 7115): Parameter name: cancel
04-28 18:58:23.145 E/mono-rt ( 7115):   at Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert (System.String title, System.String message, System.String accept, System.String cancel) [0x00009] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:147 
04-28 18:58:23.145 E/mono-rt ( 7115):   at Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert (System.String title, System.String message, System.String cancel) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:141

Comment: That is the full error, and that was inputting the char F

Comment: it looks like it does not like the empty string you are passing to DisplayAlert.  Like I already suggested.

Comment: First, its better checking for ```!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserEntry.Text)``` instead of ```!=null```. Second, you cannot pass empty string to ```DisplayAlert``` as the error complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**
The method `DisplayAlert` has three **Parameters**:

```
//   title:
//     The title of the alert dialog.
//
//   message:
//     The body text of the alert dialog.
//
//   cancel:
//     Text to be displayed on the 'Cancel' button.
```

And they are **Nonnullable** . So when you set it as null ,it will crash.

**Solution:**

Give the parameters `message` and `cancel` a value. If you do not want to it display anything .you can set them as a `space`

```
 await DisplayAlert("Please type either A,B,C,D", " ", " ");
```